# How do I mock this method in Jasmine 1.3?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm a little stuck with mocking this method if anyone can lend a hand

```
stickyBtn: function(selector, offsetSelector) {
      var btn = selector ? $(selector + ' .btn-tag') : $('.btn-tag'),
          offset = $(offsetSelector).offset();

      if (btn && offset) {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
          btn.addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
          btn.removeClass('fixed');
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What method are you trying to mock? Do you use jQuery?

Comment: Apologies. Part of the code got cut off.  It's the stickyBtn method. Yes I do use jQuery. Thanks!